# Duplicate row when multiple threads insert the same content in the mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, concurrency

I have one mysql table which looks like

### id | property_code | property_value

The id is auto increment, is the primary key in this table.

when I have multiple threads in the distributed machines, insert the same content to this table, so that a duplicate will happen.

### 1 | code_1 | value1

### 2 | code_1 | value1

I know if I set the property_code as the primary key, it will solve this problem.
is there any other solution to solve this problem if I don't want to change the primary key?

Comment: You could create a unique index on `property_code`.  I don't know if you think that is an "other solution".

Comment: You can add another constraint on the table. You might also alter the table.

Comment: The easy way out would be to implement a unique constraint to property _code.

Comment: "other solution" means the solution will don't change the schema of this table, but can solve this problem, is it possblile to do this sychronize queue in the database when insert content in the mysql, then I can control the whole insert progress? can it be done in the database layer, not the java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a unique index doesn't change the schema of the table *directly*.  You can create such an index by doing:

```
create unique index table_property_code on table(property_code);
```

This will enforce uniqueness of the value in the table, regardless of the number of simultaneous inserts and updates.

Adding a unique constraint or unique key does exactly the same thing.  If you wanted, you could do this through an `alter table` command, but you don't need to.

Just a note, your question is a little ambiguous, so you might want one unique index on both `property_code` and `property_value`.

Comment: Got it, because I don't know the different between unique index and unique constraint, I search it, and I think maybe this's a good solution. I want to confirm the different between unique index and unique constraint, the unique index is phsical structure, and unique constraint will also create unique index, so I'm confused about why I should use unique constraint? I thinks unique index is enough.